# UI test in Android occurred error on RecyclerView scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-espresso

I'm studying `uitest`, my goal is testing `RecyclerView` scrolling. When I execute example codes, this error occurs:

```
E/TestRunner: androidx.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'scroll RecyclerView to position: 17' on view 'with id: com.jakchang.hwahae:id/recyclerView'.
        at androidx.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:84)
       blabla ~~
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Action will not be performed because the target view does not match one or more of the following constraints:
```

I have been searching for this but can't find anything to solve this.
Here is my code. Help me please:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ExampleInstrumentedTest {
    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val mainActivity = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java)

    @Test
    fun useAppContext() {
        //mainActivity.launchActivity(Intent())

        Espresso.onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.recyclerView))
            .inRoot(RootMatchers.withDecorView(Matchers.`is`(mainActivity.activity.window.decorView)))
            .perform(RecyclerViewActions.scrollToPosition<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(17))
        Thread.sleep(10000)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post more of your error logs? I think your `inRoot` matcher has failed to match. You can also try removing it, pretty sure it's redundant since you have already described the activity rule.

Comment: I removed and tried, but it doesn't work